# Timelion draw a dot if log contains error

Tags: kibana, timelion

I'm using Timelion to draw my time series, but I'd like to draw points or color the lines red if the document contains an "error" field. Is there a way to do this with conditionals?

Ideally, I'd like some HUGE pointer identifying where the errors are. Below is an example of what I'm trying. The top function draws the time series I'm interested in viewing which is great, but the second one just draws bars with the count of errors at that point.

```
.es(q="_exists_:json.durationGetOwner", index=filebeat-*, metric="avg:json.durationrelinquish", split=json.environment.consensus_type:4).label('$2 $1 duration ms', '^.*duration(\S+) >.*type:(\S+).*$'),
.es(q="json.type:Error AND json.name:monitoring-tests").bars(width=1).color('#ff0000').label('Test Wide Errors')
```

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: I think you probably just have to create another line of just the error dots. I'm not sure I ever fixed this.